# Proving that the expectation of supremum of absolute value of Brownian motion over the unit interval is finite.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $(B_{t},t\geq0) $ be the standard Brownian Motion. Define $M(t)=\underset{s\in [0,t]}{\mathrm{sup}}|B_{s}|$. I want to show that $$E[M(1)] =\int_{0}^{\infty}P[M(1)>x]dx < \infty  $$
My approach so far...$$P[\underset{s\in [0,1]}{\mathrm{sup}}|B_{s}|>x] \leq P[\underset{s\in [0,1]}{\mathrm{sup}}B_{s}>x]+P[\underset{s\in [0,1]}{\mathrm{inf}}B_{s}<-x] = 2P[\underset{s\in [0,1]}{\mathrm{sup}}B_{s}>x]$$
using the fact that $B_{t}$ and $-B_{t}$ have same distribution. Now by the  reflection principle we have that $$P[\underset{s\in [0,1]}{\mathrm{sup}}B_{s}>x] = 2P[B_{1}>x]=2[1-N(x)]$$ where $N(x)$ is the cdf of $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.
Using all this I am not able to show that $E[M(1)] < \infty$. I was also thinking to use Doob's maximal inequality as $(|B_{t}|,t\geq0) $ is a submartingale with respect to canonical filtration but I guess it won't help.

Comment: Your notations are very confusing. For example, $M(t)=\underset{t\in [0,1]}{\mathrm{sup}}|B_{t}|$ ,perhaps you mean $M(t)=\underset{u\in [0,t]}{\mathrm{sup}}|B_{u}|$?

Comment: @NN2 sorry I have edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you proved, we can deduce that
$$P[\underset{s\in [0,1]}{\mathrm{sup}}|B_{s}|>x] \le 2P[\underset{s\in [0,1]}{\mathrm{sup}}B_{s}>x]$$
As $\underset{s\in [0,1]}{\mathrm{sup}}B_{s} =|B_1|$ in law and by applying the [Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Statement)  we have
$$P[\underset{s\in [0,1]}{\mathrm{sup}}|B_{s}|>x] \le 2P[|B_1|>x] < \frac{2}{x^2}  \qquad \text{for } x>0$$
Then
$$
\begin{align}
E[M(1)]&= \int_0^aP[\underset{s\in [0,1]}{\mathrm{sup}}|B_{s}|>x]dx+\int_a^{+\infty}P[\underset{s\in [0,1]}{\mathrm{sup}}|B_{s}|>x]dx \\
&\le \int_0^a1dx+\int_a^{+\infty}\frac{2}{x^2}dx=a+\frac{2}{a}<+\infty
\end{align}
$$

Q.E.D

Comment: Thanks I did not thought of breaking the integral the way you did.

Comment: @DhruvRathore You're welcome. And please don't forget to accept the answer if you think it solves your question!